# Read data from uploaded excel

Tags: excel, ado.net, memorystream, connection-string

I need to create an ASP.NET 2.0+ web application that allows the user to upload some excel files; the contents from these files should be saved into some SQL database. The problem is with the connection string one should use in ADO.NET. According to [this entry](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) (and few others from SO), one has to specify the physical path to the Excel file. This supposes that during data load, the excel file should be saved on the server's harddisk, which in my case is questionable - I can't save temporary files on hdd... Is there any other approach? like using a MemoryStream or so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will make life quite difficult for yourself if you were to stream the file, I don't even know if that is possible with Excel via ADO.NET.

I've always worked with excel documents by reading them off the physical drive - are sure you cant store the excel files temporarily?